# URL rewrite doesn't work in a Symfony2

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, symfony

I have a web site under Symfony 2 and want to have a basic URL rewrite.

Apache mod rewrite is enabled. Apache has been restarted multiple times.

```
# a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

Virtual host seems ok

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot /home/www/mydomain/web
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/www/mydomain/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's my .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But http://mydomain.com/ gives the "index of" page and I have to pass through http://mydomain.com/app.php/ to access my web site.

What am I missing ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

> When this directive is set to None and AllowOverrideList is set to
>   None .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server
>   will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.

*When not specified, [`AllowOverrideList` is set to `None`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverridelist)*

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride