# How go to home page correctly?

Tags: apache, symfony

I enable mod_rewrite but when I go to home page the browser try download something. When I go to app_dev.php the browser show error:

```
The requested URL /app_dev.php/ was not found on this server.
```

My locale host was configurated to web directory.

the output of 'app/console router:debug _welcome' is:

```
[router] Route "_welcome"
Name         _welcome
Path         /
Host         ANY
Scheme       ANY
Method       ANY
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults     _controller: Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\WelcomeController::indexAction
Requirements NO CUSTOM
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
Path-Regex   #^/$#s
```

my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myemail@email.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/symfony/hz.dev/web"
ServerName hz.dev
ServerAlias www.hz.dev
ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/hz.dev-error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/hz.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

My web/.htaccsess

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_alias.c>        
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: which route is set up for `/` in `app/config/routing.yml` ? is the `/` route being shown if you execute `app/console router:debug` ?

Comment: yes, app/console router:debug for '/' show 
`_welcome   ANY      ANY    ANY  /`

Comment: whats the output of `app/console router:debug _welcome` ?

Comment: I put it to question.

Comment: I don't think this is a router issue since he would have a `The server returned a "404 Not Found".` error in prod mode. Can you dump the content of your `.htaccess` ? Can you also show your vhost file ?

Comment: okay that's the regular demo index. Then your problem is apache-related ... please provide your .htaccess and the virtualhost configs

Comment: my app/.htaccess `deny from all`

Comment: not app/.htaccess your web/.htaccess

Comment: Can you try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548131/url-rewrite-doesnt-work-in-a-symfony2/16548435#16548435 ?

Comment: thank you for helping. I put .htaccess in question

Comment: @cheesemacfly I put 'AllowOverride All' in httpd-vhosts.conf but it didn't help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess instead. It's very simple, I use it during development.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

You should then be able to access Symfony at http://example.com/ without app_dev.php in the URL